# PHP getting form data using id attribute

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm making a form with checkboxes and radiobuttons
I use the value as price, which I calculate with a script so I get the total price of the selected checkboxes and radiobuttons.

```
<script>
function calcscore() {
    score = 0;
    $(".calc:checked").each(function () {
        score += Number($(this).val());
    });
    $("#price").text(score.toFixed(2));
    $("#sum").val(score)
}
$().ready(function () {
    $(".calc").change(function () {
        calcscore()
    });
});
</script>
```

```
<input type="radio" id="1" value="40" class= "calc" name = "780143050"> Gezichtsbehandeling (incl.)<br>
<input type="radio" id="2" value="40" class = "calc" name = "780143050"> Massage<br>
<input type="radio" id="3" value="75" class = "calc" name = "780143050"> beide 
<span id="output"></span><input type="hidden" name="sum" id="sum" value="0">
                <p>Totaal extra's : €  <span id="price">0</span>
```

I have the following PHP

test.php

```
<?php
   echo("keuze : " . $_POST['780143050'] . "<br />\n");
?>
```

I in my php script the value and the ID.  How can I echo the ID of the selected radiobutton?

Comment: are you submitting that  form?

Comment: yes, it's a snippet from the code  I do get all values but i don't get the values of ID

Comment: `value` is the field submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do this:

1. change the value of `value` to the value of the `id`
2. add the value of the `id` to the `value`

html:

```
<input type="radio" id="2" value="40|2" class = "calc" name = "780143050"> Massage<br>
```

js:

```
<script>
function calcscore() {
    score = 0;
    $(".calc:checked").each(function () {
        score += Number($(this).val().split('|')[0]);
    });
    $("#price").text(score.toFixed(2));
    $("#sum").val(score)
}
$().ready(function () {
    $(".calc").change(function () {
        calcscore()
    });
});
```

php

```
<?php
   echo("keuze : " . split('|',$_POST['780143050'])[1] . "<br />\n");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

See below code. Selected radio button ID will be received as `$_POST['selID']`:

```js
$('form').submit(function(){
   var selID = $('form input[type=radio]:selected').attr('id');
   $(this).append('<input type="hidden" name="selID" value="'+selID+'" />');
});
```